# React Native - Build successful on android but app crash

Tags: android, google-play-services, react-native

When I build (> react-native run-android) with my dependencies the build is successful !
However, when the app is launch it crash immediately ...
How don't know how is it possible, there is no error, nothing to tell me why the application is crashing...

It's sure it is from the dependencies...

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-intercom')
    implementation "io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:3.+"

    implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'

    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation project(':tipsi-stripe')
    implementation (project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
}
```

Thank you really much

Comment: This question is too broad, you need to check your gradle files for multiple instances of packages for a start.

Comment: Can you please check your logs whenever app crashes?

Comment: Which logs are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

For checking exception logs in generated release mode apk follow steps 1-3.
*(Step 1 can be skipped if signed release mode apk is already installed on device.)*

1. Make sure adb devices command lists your device then Install app on device/emulator by running below command from folder with apk.

   `adb -d install -r app-name.apk`
   ex : `adb -d install -r learnapp.apk`

*change -d to -e if you want to install on emulator.*

2. run `adb logcat | FINDSTR "Exception"`
   This will log all exception messages on cmd.
3. Now start the app and exception detail will be available on cmd.

Exceptions can be really minute problems for example i had console.clear() in one of my app screen's  componentDidMount() hook and console.clear is undefined exception was causing the crash after navigating to that screen. After running steps 1-3 I found out the exception, removed that line from code, generated apk again and app worked just fine afterwards!!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same error right now with react 0.59.8 (or even 60+). Maybe I can shed some light on to this because it really annoys me as hell, since I am not able to develop my app but focus on fixing errors related to the framework... 
So as an explanation: The project is built successfully. When cd to android subfolder and I execute

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace (or similar)
```

it says build successful.
If I run `react-native run-android` it builds also successful and tries to upload the file to the device. And then crashes without any error. I am simply back in my shell where I executed `react-native run-android` from.

Sometimes it is fixed after executing `npm start` and hitting reload on the device causing the javascript to be built/transpiled (or whatever happens there. I do not know.)

Does anybody has the same issue?

Does anybody know why it happens and can explain?

Update: adblogcat *:E throws this error when trying to connect to metro bundler which was run with `npm start` (when it does not work running npm start)

`unknown:ReactNative:   ... 21 more
09-17 10:34:38.851 29275 29275 E unknown:ReactNative: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`

my package.json:

```js
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

my MainApplication.java

```js
...

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.storage.RNFirebaseStoragePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.database.RNFirebaseDatabasePackage;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(new MainReactPackage(), new RNFirebasePackage(), new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
          new RNGestureHandlerPackage(), new ImagePickerPackage(), new RNFirebaseStoragePackage(),
          new RNFirebaseDatabasePackage());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

android/build.gradle

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */


project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf', 'FontAwesome.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"



/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bonscanner"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    }

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gradle.properties contains:

`android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true`

Answer (score 0):

This can be cause of linear gradient, I m facing same issue.

https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/455